# How to send single variable to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I want to send single variable to view but I am unable to do it, Please help me.

Controller:

```
public function src($id=""){
    $this->load->view('catsrc', $id);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
<?php echo $id ;?>
</div>
```

Error Getting:

> Message: Undefined variable: id

Comment: missing `;` after `$id` but that's only _if_ `$id` is already defined which it _isn't_.

Comment: try `$this->load->view('catsrc', [ 'id' => $id ]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert of CodeIgniter but according to [official documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html): *"Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an **array** or an **object** in the second parameter of the view loading function"*

```
$this->load->view('catsrc', [ 'id' => $id ]);
```

was that so hard ?

Happy coding :)

Comment: I upvoted because you were the first one to answer! `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter views read from a $data array. To reference $id in a view, put it in the $data array in your controller

```
$data = array('id' => 'your_value_here');
```

and pass $data to the view.

Full documentation on views lives at: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 1):

**How CI Classes Pass Information and Control to Each Other**

**Calling Views**
We have seen how the controller calls a view and passes data to it:
First it creates an array of data ($data) to pass to the view; then it loads and calls the view in the same expression:

```
$this->load->view('testview', $data);
```

You can call libraries, models, plug-ins, or helpers from within any controller, and models and libraries can also call each other as well as plug-ins and helpers.
However, you can't call one controller from another, or call a controller from a
model or library. There are only two ways that a model or a library can refer back to a controller:
Firstly, it can return data. If the controller assigns a value like this:

```
$foo = $this->mymodel->myfunction();
```

and the function is set to return a value, then that value will be passed to the variable $foo inside the controller.

This may not answer your question directly but helps!!